# Shader issue in unity3d 2d game

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, shader

I making a game in unity3d and I have a lighting there
Shader: [Link](https://vk.com/doc11904759_410228384?hash=f54c870a7f1d716fcb&dl=a8e86afb0e5f9f66a2)

but on mali 450 it runs like super slow,lighting changes every 5-7 seconds
So question:
How to fix it or how to make shader 10 times faster?

Comment: Please include your shader sources within the post. And lighting changes how exactly? Furthermore, what did you do to profile your shader? What did you narrow the issue down to? Anything else about your project/scene we need to know?

Comment: @Bart i use this asset https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/3003 i tried to do nothing, because a dont know anything about shaders. Lighting should change like VERY fast, but my issue is it changes every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I had downloaded your shader,I find there has a parameter called StartSeep,I tried to change it,and I think it change the lighting speed.

[image]